# Get device filesystem path from dev_t on macOS

Tags: c, macos, darwin

If I have a 32-bit integer BSD device number dev_t (e.g. 0x1000004) on macOS (Darwin), how can I get the corresponding filesystem path for this device (e.g. "/dev/disk1s4")?

Comment: The `/dev/diskxxx`is just a directory entry pointing to a special inode. `mknod /tmp/mydisk b 4096  4` (or similar) will probably create (an other)one for you.

Comment: So if you want to find an existing entry, you'll have to list the directory and look for it.  (Note that it might not exist at all.)  You can list the directory by invoking the `ls -l` command, or by calling `opendir`/`readdir` and then `stat`, whichever you find more convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enumerate the mounted file systems and look for one who's device ID matches. You can use `getfsstat()` for the enumeration. That fills in `struct statfs` structures. Compare the field `f_fsid.val[0]` of each structure to the `dev_t` you're looking for. If they match, then that `struct statfs` is the one for the device you're looking for and you can examine its other fields for the info you're looking for. In particular, the `f_mntfromname` is the device path.

Answer (score 2):

```
find /dev -type b -ls
```

, And check the output for major/minor == {0x1000,4}

---

Or: `find /  -type b -ls` if need to search the entire file system.

BTW: there could be more entries, referring to the same {major,minor} combination.

Answer (score 0):

The `devname` api will consume a `dev_t` and a `mode_t` and return the name of the device for you.

See `man 3 devname` or [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/devname.3.html).