# Is there a way to get a meaningful mount point for st_dev on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, stat

**Note this is a MacOS question not a Linux Question - They are different operating systems**

I'd like to get a meaningful mount point out of python's `os.stat("foo").st_dev`. At the moment this is just a number and I can't find anywhere to cross reference it.

All my searches so far have come up with answers that work on Linux by interrogating `/proc/...` but `/proc` doesn't exist in MacOS so any such answer will not work.

Comment: Would any of the methods in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453602/how-to-find-the-mountpoint-a-file-resides-on) work for you?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Linux guy, but if I were not allowed to use `/proc`, I would search the `/dev` directory for an entry (i.e. filename) which has following `stat` data:

- `st_mode` indicates that it is a block device (helper: `stat.S_ISBLK`)
- `st_rdev` matches the given `st_dev` value

Comment: How does this help the OP map a device number to something more meaningful?

Comment: @Steve It will give him a `/dev/xxx` name.

Comment: I like that this aims to be cross compatible. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over local disks, and compare the disk's `st_rdev` to the `st_dev` you got earlier.

```py
for mnt in glob.glob("/dev/disk?s*"):
    t = os.stat(mnt)
    if t.st_rdev == s.st_dev:
      print(mnt)
```

[Get device filesystem path from dev_t on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790858/get-device-filesystem-path-from-dev-t-on-macos) basically confirms this information, but of course, isn't strictly a duplicate.

For what it's worth, `diskutil list -plist` prints a machine-readable XML property list of all disk identifiers, and `diskutil info -plist disk1s1` (for example) prints information for a particular disk; but this does not include the `dev_t` information that you get from `os.stat().st_rdev`

Annoyingly, `diskutil` does not have a manual page on my system, but [here is a (possibly old) on-line version.](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/diskutil.html)

The [getdevinfo package on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/getdevinfo/) appears to provide a Python binding to most of this information, though https://www.hamishmb.com/html/Docs/developer/getdevinfo/macos.html looks rather spare.

Comment: This is just background which basically confirms the other answer; you should probably accept that.